# How can I diagnose why websockets are not working?

Tags: networking

I recently got a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro, and tried to connect to a website (smashladder.com/netplay) which uses websockets for a chat server. I am able to connect fine with my phone and Mac, but on my Lenovo I can't do so. websocketstest.com returns [this](http://websocketstest.com/result/439773) in Chrome and [this](http://websocketstest.com/result/439777) in Firefox. I turned off all antiviruses and firewalls. How can I diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a while back. Lenovo installs this spyware called visual discovery, remove it and reboot.

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Security-Malware/Potentially-Unwanted-Program/td-p/1794457